# How to start a Stata process in Emacs (with the ESS package) in Windows

Tags: windows, emacs, stata, ess

In the ESS (Emacs speaks Statistics) manual, it says if I use Cygwin bash shell, I should run `M-x S RET`.

and if MSDOS prompt shell, run something like `M-x S+6-msdos RET`.

so what's the proper syntax for starting a Stata process? I tried `M-x stata-msdos RET`, `M-x sta-msdos`, and `M-x Stata-msdos` and failed.

EDIT 1: I'm using Windows 8.1 and MSDOS prompt shell (this is the shell pops up when I use `M-x shell`)

It seems there is some problem when I use `M-x stata RET` (might not be the right command for msdos shell), instead of opening a new buffer in Stata mode, Emacs starts Stata in its own window and leaves the old Emacs window irresponsive, which I have to force kill in the end.

EDIT 2: I asked roughly the same question in the ess mailing list and someone mentioned that it seems in Windows Stata Can only be used with its own GUI, not the command line, and that explains why when I `M-x stata RET` it always opens its own window ( I thought it was because I was using the wrong command). I asked the question because I didn't see the question being asked, now I guess I understand (sadly) why: because it can not be solved..

Comment: So from your attempts it looks like you're using an MSDOS shell.  Have you tried typing in `M-x stata` and then hitting `TAB` to look for completions?

Comment: Those all failed *how*? Do  you get anything interesting in `*Messages*`?

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity, failed means that when I use `M-x sta RET`, emacs says `no match`

Comment: just tried `TAB`, and I got four alternatives: `stata`, `stata-help-mode`, `stata-mode` `stata-review-window`, both the `stata` and `stata-mode` open Stata in its own window and leave the Emacs window irresponsive (which I have to force kill).